Can American ‘bought’ sometimes sound like ‘bop’?
In American English, I’ve noticed that the word bought sometimes sounds like bop when followed by a word starting with a bilabial consonant, such as [p], [b], or [m].
For example, She bought me a car sounds like [ʃɪ ˈbɑp m̩i (j)ə ˈkʰɑɹ].
Is this a valid interpretation?

Do you have a clip we can listen to? Are you sure you aren't mishearing a glottal stop there, so [ˈbɔʔ] instead? Have you transcribed she as though it were the start of ship to show the weak pronoun? If so, why didn't you do so for me as well? Why have you marked [m] as a syllabic consonant? Your curious choice of the FATHER vowel for bought suggests you may be listening to Los Angeles or Hollywood natives.

Short answer (tl;dr):
Yes, the last consonant in the word bought may often be realised as a [p] before the word me.

The full story
In General American, a syllable final /t/ followed by a consonant will most often be realised as a glottal stop, [ʔ]. Alternatively, it may be realised as a glottally reinforced alveolar stop, where there is a complete closure of the glottis swiftly followed by a complete closure made by the tongue at the alveolar ridge (that little shelf behind your top teeth). In other words, it may be realised as [ ʔt ]. Lastly, for our purposes, it may even be realised as [t].
A canonical /t/, in other words a /t/ realised as [t], is made using the tongue at the alveolar ridge, and is thus dubbed an 'alveolar' consonant. The other alveolar consonants in English are /t d n s z l/.  In English all the consonants made on the alveolar ridge are highly unstable and variously subject to different phonological and phonetic processes. Such processes include but are not limited to:

elision (being omitted)
de-alveolar assimilation (being made at a different point in the mouth from the alveloar ridge depending on preceding or following sounds)
assimilation of manner (becoming a different type of sound when influenced by an adjacent sound)
assimilation of voicing (becoming voiced or devoiced under the influence of adjacent sounds)
coalescent assimilation (fusing together with an adjacent sound to produce a third sound different from either of the two original sounds)
having allophones that are very radically different from their canonical realisations depending on their position in the syllable

The process that is affecting what the Original Poster is hearing is ᴅᴇ-ᴀʟᴠᴇᴏʟᴀʀ ᴀssɪᴍɪʟᴀᴛɪᴏɴ,  which is a specific type of ᴀssɪᴍɪʟᴀᴛɪᴏɴ ᴏғ ᴘʟᴀᴄᴇ. All of the alveolar consonants are subject to de-alveolar assimilation to some degree, but this happens most of all with the consonants /t, d, n/.
When the consonants /t, d, n/ precede a bilabial consonant (one made with the lips), in other words when they precede the consonants /p, b, m/ and to a lesser extent /w/, they will themselves often become bilabial. So /t/ will change to /p/, /d/ to /b/, and /n/ to /m/. Here are some examples:

Google dot com --> Google dok com.
good practice --> goob practice
red wine --> reb wine
go sunbathing --> go sumbathing

So, in those cases where a General American speaker might use a syllable-final [t] or a syllable-final glottally reinforced /t/, i.e. [ ʔt ], they might use [p] or [ ʔp ] when the next word or syllable happens to begin with a bilabial.
This is exactly what is happening in the Original Poster's example, where the /t/ at the end of the word bought precedes the bilabial /m/, the first segment in the word me. In the cases which the Original Poster is thinking of, the speakers have a COT-CAUGHT or  possibly a PALM, LOT, THOUGHT (there are several possibilities) merger; in other words they have the same vowel in those two (or three) words. This means that for such speakers the words bop and bought may sound identical when preceding a word beginning with a bilabial.
Note, however, that the last consonant in bought may be realised as a [p] in such environments regardless of the realisation of the vowel.
Giving the Original Poster the benefit of the doubt therefore, as we rightly should, their transcription of what they are hearing is basically correct1:

[ʃi ˈbɑp mi ə ˈkʰɑɹ]

The Original Poster has razor sharp ears!
That's all folks!

1Technically,  the [m] should not be syllabic, and we need the same vowels at the end of me and she. I've used [ɑ] in the words bought and car as per the American transcription given in the Cambridge Dictionary .

Can’t buy this: “red wine --> reb wine”

@TinfoilHat Well-attested, though.

@TinfoilHat Maybe you might prefer "sam(b)widge"?

Nah, “samwitch" here (West Coast). The “(b)w” sounds like you have a cold. Where y’all attesting from?

@TinfoilHat I definitely assimilate the /d/ in "red wine," but the resulting sound isn't really a [b], since my lips sort of tighten but don't actually close. Dunno what the right transcription for the sound I'm making is.

Excellent answer as always, @Araucaria-Him!

(Incidentally, when I say it out loud, I actually don't think "she" and "me" end in the same vowel sound; the former does get reduced to something like /ʃə/ or /ʃɪ/. This only seems to happen before consonants, though; in "She offered me a car" the words "she" and "me" do end in the same sound.)

@alphabet I think that's happening the other way round maybe. It's because of the following vowel after me that the vowel seems a tad more FLEECE-like, and thus when you have ordered after she you get the same effect. What most phoneticians would say is that there's a jod-style glide gesture inserted between the vowels. This phenomenon rather puts the damper on Geoff's description of FLEECE as a diphthong ending in a consonantal jod. Because where does it disappear to (and why) when the next sound is a consonant? (Or rather, why is there a difference between the two environemtents?)

@Araucaria-Him Quite possibly. (Geoff's view, as I recall from elsewhere, is that the FLEECE vowel is a very narrow diphthong--one whose start and endpoints are quite close together--and that for this reason it can easily become compressed into a pure monophthong in various environments.)

I think it might be useful to note that said assimilation is not aspirated. In fact, the glotalization is often still present.

As an orthographic shorthand, reb wine sort of works, but it does hide the fact that the assimilation there is less complete than in, say, rek coat or reb boat. An actual full bilabial closure may be attested, but it is not the norm (I’m sure you could find attestations of reg wine, too). It would be much more common to pronounce it as @alphabet describes – lips narrowing and rounding in preparation for [w], but without fully closing, and maintaining a partial (though incomplete) glottal constriction. Something like ['ɹεβ̰ʷ.'waɪn] would be a reasonable way to transcribe it.

@Araucaria-Him What you’ve written is fine—but I have ᴍᴀᴊᴏʀ disagreements with Cambridge’s transcriptions. They always use ᴜɴʀᴏᴜɴᴅᴇᴅ  /ɑ/ for ᴀʟʟ American English despite ❶this pronunciation being mainly west of the Rockies thus misrepresenting the ᴍᴀᴊᴏʀɪᴛʏ and misleading foreigners; ❷their own sound clips of Americans ᴀʟʟ ʀᴏᴜɴᴅ that vowel yet that’s ɴᴏᴛ what their own IPA shows❗See all, taught, log.

Is this real? I've lived all over the US and never heard anything like reb wine or she bawp me something from an adult.

The slight ᴘʜᴏɴᴇᴛɪᴄ off-glides in word-final tense vowels compress and often disappear in many American accents before many but not quite all consonant codas. So like May Day [mej dej] can become mate date [met det] but never [mɛt dɛt]. This happens with all ᴘʜᴏɴᴇᴛɪᴄ “diphthongs” in American English including even key, toe, shoe /ij,ow,uw/ in some environments — but ɴᴏᴛ with the three actual ᴘʜᴏɴᴇᴍɪᴄ diphthongs as in boy, cow, buy /oj,aw,aj/. The effect’s not limited to Minnesota and Wisconsin where it’s famous (or notorious) but also occurs in numerous other regions as well.

@Aruralreader You've heard it, but you haven't heard it! When you turn up for your first phonetics class, they get you to transcribe what you hear. Then they tell you what was actually said, and none of the students believe them. Then you listen again, or they chop bits up for you and isolate them, and it's absolutely mind-bending all the stuff that you've never noticed before and also all the tricks that your mind plays on you while you're processing stuff!

You have explained what this is, but not why.

@Lambie read the question again. The OP doesn't ask "why" but whether their interpretation is "valid". In any case, the "how" is also the reason “When the consonants /t, d, n/ precede a bilabial consonant, […] /p, b, m/ and to a lesser extent /w/, they will themselves often become bilabial.”

@Lambie That clearly can't be the main reason, though. It's 'easier' to say "a phanton night" that "a phantom night", but the former is not an alternative pronunciation of the latter in English.

All these changes to a sound are due to one being easier than another. Otherwise, they would not have arisen. Now, you have given another one. It's not about alternative pronunciations: it's about being easier to move from one articulation to another for two sounds (phones).

@Lambie It's no easier to go from /m/ to /m/ than it is to go from /n/ to /n/, and no more difficult to go from /n/ to /m/ than from /m/ to /n/. So your theory that, for example, "tem minutes"  occurs because it's easier, needs to explain why assimilation doesn't occur in  "denim necktie". Both "denin necktie" and "denim mecktie" are badly formed! So it's not a simple case of consonants assimilating because it's easier to say!

You are now changing the original examples. "good practice" (d precedes p), it's easier to go from b to p [goob practice] than d to p [good practice} was the original example. If it were not easier, what would be the point of it? Hm? I haven't thought about these others yet.

@Lambie step down versus step bown versus stet down shows the same problem ;-)

For the same reason. It's harder to transition from p (voiceless, bilabial) to d (dental, voiced) than from p (voiceless, bilabial) to b (voiced also bilabial). And stet down, dunno what that means. How about flat down [feathers]. t to d is also voiceless and voiced,

@Lambie "It's harder to transition from p (voiceless, bilabial) to d (dental, voiced) than from p (voiceless, bilabial) to b (voiced also bilabial)" Yes, exactly, so why is step down ok and step bown not ok? The question for stet down is why isn't it licit - given that it too involves /d/s and /p/s and /t/s and is easier to say because it involves two homorganic consonants, just like all the other examples of assimilation we've discussed.

You have systematically discounted the original examples I gave by giving other ones. "stet down" is NOT English. whereas "flat down" is. Anyway, there is assimilation because the pronunciation is eaisier due to articulatory transitions being easier. Were it not so, they would not exist. Give me one that goes from harder to easier.

@Lambie Flat down is not an example of assimilation. Those already have the same place of articulation!

Well, stet down is not English! And I said nothing about the phones, did I in that regard?

@Lambie The reason that "goob practice" is easier is that the /b/ and /p/ are homorganic - made at the same place. "Good practice" is more difficult because the /d/ and /p/ happen at different places (alveolar ridge and lips). So the 'easier pronunciation' theory needs to explain why "Step down" (lips and alveolar ridge) cannot assimilate to "Stet down" (both alveolar) or "step bown" (both bilabial), both of which would be 'easier ' to say!

@TinfoilHat The (b) just means that the /b/, like the /d/, is optional. Where did the /m/ in your "samwitch"  come from? ;-)


I've noticed that the word 'bought' sometimes sounds like 'bop'

What is said is  [ʃɪ ˈbɑt m̩i (j)ə ˈkʰɑɹ].
This is an example of the cot-caught merger (chiefly found in the eastern western side of the USA. The following consonant is unstressed (sometimes to the point of inaudibility) but, basically, unchanged.

Alas, that entire matter is far too complex to reduce to any broad statement that's also true enough to be applicable everywhere. You have to look not just at COT–CAUGHT but also at rounded LOT and the “On” line and at multiple mergers and splits in COT–CAUGHT, FATHER–BOTHER, FATHER–PALM, FOUGHT–FART, LOT–CLOTH, CLOTH–THOUGHT, GONE–LAWN, TRAP–BATH — plus several others besides.

@Peter Shor Thank you. I have edited.

No, it sounds like bopme because it is easier to say a p than a t followed by an m. For the t in bought, you have to first stop the air and then say the bilabial m[e]. This is not "bought" without context. "She bought me a car". I guess most answerers aren't thinking about ease of articulation.

@Lambie That clearly can't be the main reason, though. It's 'easier' to say "a phanton night" that "a phantom night", but the former is not an alternative pronunciation of the latter in English.
